# How to access /storage/emulated/10 (multi-users env) in adb shell on Android 9+ without root access?

Tags: adb, storage, multi-user, file-permissions

I have two Android system users configured.

```
$ pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10:security space:13} running
    UserInfo{999:XSpace:800010} running
```

When the mobile is running at Android 8.1, I can access the secondary user's space `/storage/emulated/10` easily in `adb shell`.

But after I upgrade to Android 9, I can no longer do it:

```
$ ls /storage/emulated/10
ls: /storage/emulated/10: Permission denied
```

Any ideas how I can access my second user's space in `adb shell`?

Btw, my `/sdcard/` always points to the first user's space `/storage/emulated/0` at `adb shell` regardless what my current user is at mobile UI. The `adb shell` connection remains the same when I switch users at mobile UI too.

When I switch users at mobile UI level, my adb connection remains the same. And I do see the current user changes with the following command:

```
$ dumpsys activity | grep mCurrentUser
    mCurrentUser=0
$ dumpsys activity | grep mCurrentUser
    mCurrentUser=10
```

Answer (score 12):

### WHY IS ADB DENIED ACCESS TO MULTI-USER STORAGE?

Access to `/storage/emulated/10` is denied from `adb shell` due to [this change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/d7e51760430bc06617e7b42c77a8f4cfde80d041) in Android 9:

> *Add "default_normal" support to `vold`.
>
>   This new flag isolates each user on a multi-user device for security reasons.*

What the mount option `default_normal` does in `sdcardfs` is explained [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/a56758feb0ba81d25de1edb7a5536a7042cc0a8f):

> *The `default_normal` option causes mounts with the gid set to `AID_SDCARD_RW` to have user specific gids, as in the normal case.*

The whole story is about Android's filesystem emulation in order to have a permission-less directory (`/sdcard`) which makes file sharing among multiple UNIX users (apps) possible. It's achieved through mount namespaces and different ***VIEWs*** of `/data/media` mounted in `/mnt/runtime/`. Apps belonging to secondary as well as primary user have **isolated mount namespaces**. For details please see [**What is the “u#_everybody” UID?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526) and [**What is /storage/emulated/0/?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526).

> Btw, my `/sdcard/` always points to the first user's space `/storage/emulated/0` at `adb shell` regardless what my current user is at mobile UI.

For all native processes running in root mount namespace (including `adbd`), `/sdcard` is a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0` and `/storage/emulated` is bind mounted from `/mnt/runtime/default`. The device owner's (User_ID: 0) files in `/storage/emulated/0` have ownership `root:sdcard_rw (0:1015)` and permission mode `0771`, while secondary profile/user's (say with User_ID: 10) files in `/storage/emulated/10` have ownership `0:1001015`.

It means that non-root processes can read the directories only if they are members of supplementary groups: `0001015`, `1001015`, `11001015` and so on, *"others"* can only traverse the directories. Since `adbd` is [member of](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/adb/daemon/main.cpp#108) only `1015` GID, it can read only device owner's files, not of secondary users.

However up to Android 8 there was an exception to the above rule: to all the processes running in root mount namespace (non-app processes), `sdcardfs` always returned the directories `/storage/emulated/[N]` owned by GID `1015`. So `adb` was able to read these directories. However the exception has been removed in Android 9 using mount option `default_normal`.

---

### HOW TO ACCESS MULTIPLE-USERS FILES FROM `ADB`?

**WITH ROOT ACCESS:**

You can mount the emulated filesystem without `default_normal` option:

```
~# umount /mnt/runtime/*/emulated
~# /system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -m -w -G /data/media emulated
```

Or to make changes permanent, replace `sdcard` binary with a shell script:

```
~# cd /system/bin/; mv sdcard sdcard.bin; touch sdcard
~# chown 0.2000 sdcard*; chmod 0755 sdcard*
~# chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 sdcard
~# chcon u:object_r:sdcardd_exec:s0 sdcard.bin
```

`/system/bin/sdcard` (remove `-i` argument passed by `vold`):

```
#!/system/bin/sh

set -- $(echo "$*" | sed 's/-i //')
/system/bin/sdcard.bin $*
```

After reboot you should be able to read files in `/storage/emulated/10` from `adb shell`.

**WITHOUT ROOT ACCESS:**

On Android 9+ filesystem level access to secondary users/profiles is not possible from `adb` on `user` builds of ROMs (i.e. without root). Only interaction through [`adb` commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) which support `--user` option (`am`, `pm`, `content` etc.) is possible. Documented in [What’s in Android 9 for enterprise apps](https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-9.0#developer_tools_access):

> *"To help keep work data in the work profile, the Android Debug Bridge (adb) tool can’t access directories and files in the work profile."*

If the files owned by secondary users are accessible to primary user (through `adb` or any other means, except through Device/Work Policy Controller app), it breaks the intended isolation between users/profiles which is controlled through Android APIs. See more details in [**How to share files between regular account and work account?**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526)

It should be noted that Android Debugging Bridge (`adb`) is meant to be used by developers for debugging, not by end users. That's why a fully-managed device owner can [completely disable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setGlobalSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) `adb`.

There's a **suggested workaround** to transfer data with secondary users/profiles as explained in [Testing Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user-testing#content-provider):

> *"`adb` (or more accurately the `adbd` daemon) always runs as the system user (user ID = 0) regardless of which user is current. Therefore device paths that are user dependent (such as `/sdcard/`) always resolve as the system user."
>
>   ...
>
>   "Access to `/sdcard` paths of secondary users is denied starting in Android 9."
>
>   ...
>
>   "Because `adb` runs as the system user and data is sandboxed in Android 9 and higher, you must use **content providers** to push or pull any test data from a nonsystem user."*

For instance to transfer `test.jpg` file to `/storage/emulated/10/Pictures/` run the following commands from `adb shell`:

```
~$ content insert --user 10 --uri content://media/external/images/media/ --bind _display_name:s:test.jpg
~$ ID=$(content query --user 10 --projection _id --uri content://media/external/images/media/ --where _display_name=\'test.jpg\' | grep -o '_id=[0-9]*' | cut -d= -f2)
~$ content write --user 10 --uri content://media/external/images/media/$ID < test.jpg
```

However it's not a practical approach for bulk data transfers on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I have upvoted it because it provides very detail explanation about this problem. But due to I want to access the directory without root access, I can not mark it as the answer for now. In theory, I know the 2nd user password (I am the 2nd user), I should be able to access my own files/photos. If there is no way to achieve it, google did something extremely wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: @sgon00 personally I neither use `adb` for data transfer, nor Work Profiles. Also I'm not sure what's Google's stance on this issue. But in my opinion if the files owned by secondary user are accessible to primary user (through `adb` or any other means, except through Device/Work Policy Controller app), it nullifies the whole purpose of Work Profile. Note that the Work Profiles are not to use duplicate apps, but for isolation. So this enhanced isolation in Android 9 is justified. I wanted to write a few lines on this in my answer but keeping in view the length of the answer I didn't.

Comment: Just saw this good answer. So I cannot mkdir to emulated/10 too?

Comment: @user12158726 yes. If `/storage/emulated/10` isn't accessible, you can't read or write anything.

Comment: So i must root the phone. It is nothing to do with It policy setup?

Answer (score 0):

Shared folder for all users is `/storage/emulated/*/Android/obb`

where `*` = userid