# What’s the best way to migrate data from multiple user profiles on a Samsung tablet?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-smart-switch

I have a Samsung galaxy tab s4 with several user profiles.  I bought a new Samsung galaxy tab s6 lite that I would like to migrate to.  However, when I used smart switch, it only transfers the admin account without the additional user profiles.  Smart switch does not seem to support user profiles at all.  Third party apps like CloneIT don’t seem to connect. Is the normal method in this case manually copying everything by hand?   What is the best way to migrate multiple user profile data to a new Samsung tablet?

Comment: I believe the answer is there is no native support for backups or migration because of isolated mount namespaces so one method is to use the adb [as shown here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221122/how-to-access-storage-emulated-10-multi-users-env-in-adb-shell-on-android-9/221534#221534)