# Where does the work profile app data stored? How to access them?

Tags: samsung, file-management, work-profiles

I am using Total Commander to view files in phone storage. I only see `/emulated/0`. I need to view and modify files in my work profile.

Any `adb command` or tool I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Run `adb shell pm list users` to get a list of users. I have a work profile set up through Island, so I get

```
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running
    UserInfo{10: Island :50100030} running
```

The first number on each line is the user ID. This means the system user stores its files at `/storage/emulated/0/`, while Island (work profile) uses `/storage/emulated/10/`, at least on my device.

To access this directory, [refer to this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221534).