# How to share files across multiple user in Android 10

Tags: applications, file-system, multi-user, android-10, file-sharing

I am implementing a app in which I am creating one file using openFileOutput API in Android.
The file is saved to /data/data/com.xx.xx/files/

Now when I am switching to secondary user(multi user) I am not able to access that file from my app.

Earlier we used to have obb directly where we can share files across multiple users. But in Android 10 it is not possible.

So in Android 10 what are the ways to share files across multiple users?
Or
Where should I place my file so that it can be accessed from secondary user(multiuser) in my app.

Comment: Related: [How to share files between regular account and work account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526)

Comment: With root access you can mount `sdcardfs` without `unshared_obb` mount option to continue using OBB directory for file sharing on Android 10. However it may break some apps using OBB files. I haven't tested/studied it in-depth.