# How to access "Work Profile" files via USB on my PC

Tags: usb, google-account, file-system, file-transfer, restricted-profiles

I've got an Android "Work Profile" on my phone, kind of setup [as explained here](https://blogs.vmware.com/euc/2017/12/android-byod-how-i-use-the-work-profile.html).

It's trivial to access normal Android files. Plug a USB cable into my phone and PC, select "File Transfer" and my files show up in Windows Explorer. Is it possible to access my "Work Profile" files in the same manner? I don't see any path to them in Windows Explorer when connected (to Android 11) via USB. I'm guessing this access may not be possible.

Comment: Different questions but relevant answers: [How to access /storage/emulated/10 (multi-users env) in adb shell on Android 9+ without root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221122/218526) and [How to share files between a regular account and a work account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a file sharing app, such as AirDroid, to access your files in Work Profile.