# How to setup employee device without Google Cloud

Tags: device-administrator, android-enterprise

My organization has several phones which I would like to setup for employee use.  It appears that the Google Admin app has this functionality but requires a Google Cloud subscription.
If possible I would like to know what my alternatives are.  I want to be able to manage what apps are installed on the devices and allow app installs but be able to at least monitor what is being installed allong with basic features as an admin.

Comment: If you want device management, you'll have to look at some type of [Enterprise Mobility Management](https://www.android.com/enterprise/) [solution provider](https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/emm/?_ga=2.17976569.1761133914.1568132914-224451218.1562091936). Note that you may already have some path with your existing IT solution partner.

Comment: I don't have an IT solution partner.  We are a small company.  I'd like to know what my options are. Yes, I'm looking for "full device management" of about 3 phones for now.  Is there an app for that or do I need to go through Google and am I forced to pay them?

Comment: I have no idea the cost involved but I was hoping it would be near free  or around $5/month.  We don't have a big budget here.

Comment: I checked out some of those providers and it seems overwhelming.  I just have a small company with 3 devices.  Isn't there something in the play store I can use to govern my 3 devices but allow employees to use them?  At first I tried parental control apps but they just barely miss the mark

Comment: 1. Edit your post with your details as to why parental controls aren't enough. 2. Also [Google Workspace](https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html) for Business Starter does seem to have some [basic mobile device management features](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7400753?hl=en), but check if the plan has the [features you need](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7576736).

Comment: It should be obvious though; the phones are for adults to use.  Parental controls imply the devices be setup for children.  Many of them require that you enter a birthdate and name for the child.  In my case they are all for employee use.

Comment: Depending on how the devices need to be setup, your "child" doesn't need to be a real person with a real birthdate. Regardless, stackexchange sites are for Q&A than forum so the links provided should provide one direction for investigation.

Comment: Thank you.  I have the information I need now to possibly better phrase the question.   But now I first need to answer another question in another thread.

Comment: It seems that I need to first learn how to generate an IT Admin code that I can use to "enroll" devices.  Once I learn that, I will be able to understand what it means to use an alternative solution to Google enrollment program.  I hate the idea that my business devices are all basically owned by Google if I go through them.  By using Google to become an admin to several devices, I make Google the overarching admin, which aggravates me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118095/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-joshua-robison).

Comment: Might help in understanding concepts: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231596/218526