# Security concern: Can "multiple user" feature protect my sensitive data from apps that I don't trust?

Tags: security, lineageos, multi-user, file-permissions, background-process

I'm using lineageos18.1 and for some reason I need to install an app that I don't trust. It requires some critical permission to run normally such as:

- All files access
- Install unknown apps
- Get information about other apps

I discovered that lineageos support multiple user, and it's a good isolation tool after a few search on duckduckgo. I created a user A from admin user and installed the app B(the one I mentioned before) there. However, I'm uncertain about the followings:

- Can B access files from my admin user?
- Can B know what apps I have installed on my admin user?
- Is B still running at background once I quit user A and switch to admin user?
- If it does, will this background process of B install any app on my admin user?
- If I delete user A, does all the data from user A erased, or I have to clean them manually?

Comment: Encrypted and selinux enforced, but not rooted.

Comment: Wow, that's helpful! But I'm still uncertain about question 3 and 5.

Comment: 3). If you logout from the secondary user, no app there will be running, though its native process may remain running. Read more [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#effects). 5). Everything is deleted. You don't need to clean manually. Read more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526). // Also be clear on Android's two different features: multi-users vs. profiles. Some explanation [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526).