# Access cloned apps data in Android 12

Tags: file-management, android-12, miui-13

I am trying to extract the image folder for the cloned Telegram app from my Redmi Note 10 Pro (Android 12, MIUI 13.0.15, no root), but with no success.

This folder is under `/emulated/999/android/data`, but no file explorer seem to be able to read its content and Google hasn't been able to give me a solution so far.

Is there a way to actually access that folder, either through the phone or with a Windows/Linux PC?

Comment: You can try t use `adb` from a PC via USB. You need to install adb and driver on PC side and enable developer options + adb on Android side.

Comment: `but no file explorer seem to be able to read its content` -- that's because your file manager apps are installed for the user 0, while you're trying to access content of user 999. So that's not gonna work. You can install file manager app for user 999 (in other words, make a clone of your file manager app). Open that cloned file manager, and you should be able to see those files. Another thing, MTP won't give you access to those files.

Comment: Also ADB won't give access to files owned by secondary users. Details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221534/218526). Also related: [How to share files between regular account and work account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221593/218526)

Comment: @Firelord i obviously tried that, but with no luck.

Comment: Is your cloned File manager able to list other files for user 999? Is the telegram's folder under Android/data not visible?

Comment: Regardless of the cloned Telegram, is the original Telegram app's data shown on the file manager?

Comment: @Firelord yep it is, but when i open the android/data folder no data is shown

Comment: @AndrewT. If i use a non-cloned file manager with special permissions, it can read that folder