# how to to restore apps without reinstalling them after ROM change

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, restore, partitions, app2sd

I installed a custom `rom` on my `Android` phone which is `havoc  GSI 3.1`   I am not happy with certain features that don't work and I would like to go back to the original ROM what is preventing me from doing that is the fear of losing my `app data` and building the phone from scratch. all my `app APK` files as well as the `data` be it internal or external is on the second `partition` of my memory card ( `app2sd` )  . now if I change the ROM and go back to `OEM` I do not want to go through the hassle of restoring all app data. `titanium backup` used to be good at doing it but now it's crappy and it does not do its job especially if there is a change in the architecture between phones or version changes in the OS. besides it will just hang whenever it cannot restore the app and you have to start all over again in batch mode. my understanding is that there is no `registry` equivalent in Android what we find in windows. so is there a method where I can recreate the links and point em to existing APK files on my second partition.  the other option would be in `Nandroid` backup of my internal data and then restore it to `OEM`.  which of these approaches should work..

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763

Comment: the registry is /data/system/packages.xml

Comment: @alecxs packages.xml only contains the app listing not the app settings hence it is not really comparable to Windows registry.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217452