# How to grant “Allow always” for Geolocalization to an app?

Tags: permissions, gps-tracking, background-process

I’ve got an android mobile phone. It’s a Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro, with MIUI Global 12.0.1 (Android 11). I installed 3 applications for global position background tracing:

- OruxMap
- Komoot
- View Ranger

Only for OruxMap, in AppInfo, under the option “App permissions” > “Geolocalization”, I’ve got 4 options:

- Allow always
- Allow while the app is in use
- Ask every time
- Deny

But **for the other apps I can’t find “Allow always”** and I’ve got only the other 3 options. I compared my situation with two friends with the same 3 apps on their smartphones. One friend never sees “Allow always” option. The other sees “Allow always” option for different applications.

In order to grant background geolocalization for tracking purposes to the application of my choice, how can I visualize the “Allow always” option in the App Info for a specific application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Allow Always* permission option (via app settings options) is available **only** if the app asks for background location permission (`ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`). This is explained in developer documentation [Background Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background).

Komoot and View Ranger apps **do not** ask for background location permission (see permissions listed under the app on Play Store or view the app manifest) . Hence you do not see that option in app settings.

If an app doesn't ask for a permission, user can't grant it, unless the device is rooted and that too in some cases. See [Irfan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/131553) for detailed explanation in a similar case (though, for a different permission).

There isn't much you can do about this except look for alternative apps that ask for background location permission and meeting your needs.

Comment: Ok: I see. I also realised that OruxMap on my device is been installed from apk downloaded directly from their site, hence we're comparing different versions. Tnx